# Clipping Mask in Illustrator using Photoshop image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have two photoshop pngs, I am trying to simulate a rotating coin 3D effect.  One image will act as heads and the other will act as tails.  How can I get these two images to rotate together to simulate the front and back of a coin spinning on a 0 axis?  Output to be either a gif or mpeg4.  Here is an image of the heads side of the coin.  Both images are 512 x 512 with a radius of 80.

Can this be done in photoshop, illustrator, or something else?
How do I get an image on the back of the image below to look as if the image is double sided?

[image]

Comment: How are you bringing the Photoshop image into Illustrator? Are you drawing any paths in Illustrator? You need a path to designate as the clipping mask. Are you trying to make THAT image a clipping mask? Do you, by chance, actually want an opacity mask? You've provided very, very little information.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information I am very knowledgeable with photoshop, but illustrator I am not.  in fact I just started using it today, because I am trying to create a 3D effect on an image.

Comment: Lack of knowledge isn't a problem at all :) That's why we're all here :) But you do need to detail what you are trying to do in order for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information I am very knowledgeable with photoshop, but illustrator I am not.  In fact I just started using it today, because I am trying to create a 3D effect on an image.  I can bring it over to illustrator anyway I need to, path or not. For me the first thing is to bring the image over to illustrator so I can create the mask, then 3D effect the image and finally place a different image as the back of the 3d image.  Basically when it rotates it shows one image on one side and other on the other side.  I thought illustrator would be my best bet. @Scott

Comment: How are you intending to "rotate" the image so both sides are visible? Please edit your question and provide clear, detailed, explanations of what you have and what you want to end up with. You may not need a clipping mask in Illustrator at all. In fact, from the sound of that last comment, you may not need Illustrator.

Comment: Using a coin analogue, to better express my end goal.  On one side of a nickel, you have heads, on the other side you have tails.  Hold the coin with your index and thumb, so heads is facing you (all axis points should be zero) and rotate that coin with your opposite index finger, as it rotates you see one side then the other.  This same motion is what I am trying to capture, but with two 512 x 512 images with a corner radius of 80.  One image represents the heads and the other represents the tails.  The 3D effect is needed so when the side of the coin is visible, it looks beveled. @Scott

Comment: erm.... I understand the concept. What I don't understand is what you already have..... and what the final output would be - an animation? Static images? A video? an interactive swf? Please **edit your question and provide details**. Everything you've explained in these comments should be part of your question, in addition to how what you already have is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

What's the end goal? GIF can only have 1bit alpha, so you'll end up with bad masking, if you're trying to use the animation on top of something else that's unknown. MPEG4/H.264 does support an alpha channel, but you may have difficulty generating what you're after.

If the end goal is for use on the web, CSS3 animation can do what you're after with just the two images.

If the end goal is for use in an iOS app, then again, there's ways to animate using CoreAnimation that will only require the two sides as individual PNG images.

If the end goal is for use as part of a video, then you may be better off doing the 3D rotate within Final Cut Pro X or Premier or whatever you're editing in.

If the end goal is for use in a presentation, then Keynote can do the card flip already.

So I think the best solution may be a totally different approach. If you do want to animate within Illustrator or Photoshop, then you'll probably have to create each frame individually — a painful and slow process that will make things like getting timing and easing right very difficult. For example, you may want to have the animation start slow, pick up speed, then slow down near the end. It's easy to have an ease-in-out timing curve with CSS3 animation or CoreAnimation, but harder when you're editing by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message you've got is quite a good hint. To make a clipping mask in Ill you have to have at least a) object you want to clip, b) a vector path you want to use as a clipping mask. The a) should be arranged *below* b). Now having both selected (you may want to use “Layers” palette to get a good view what's selected) you should choose Object->Clipping Mask->Make from main menu. For more complete explanation with some examples take a look at Adobe's [Ill help page](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html) (topic: “Clipping masks”).

The other thing IMHO you could be attempting to do and asking for is using Photoshop's clipping path saved with Ps file as clipping mask in Ill, but that's quite different story :).